# How to display Unicode character in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, display, unicode

Unicode character "CIRCLED DIGIT SIX" displays like

[image]

in my Emacs. How to let it show correctly?  I'm using

```
GNU Emacs 23.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0, NS apple-appkit-1038.36)
 of 2012-02-27 on beta.macosforge.org
```

#### Edit: what font should I choose?  How do I know which supports unicode?

```
Click <mouse-2> on a completion to select it.
In this buffer, type RET to select the completion near point.

Possible completions are:
-apple-Al_Bayan-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Al_Bayan-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-American_Typewriter-bold-normal-condensed-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-American_Typewriter-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-American_Typewriter-medium-normal-condensed-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-American_Typewriter-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Andale_Mono-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
-apple-AppleGothic-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-AppleMyungjo-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Apple_Braille-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Apple_Chancery-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Apple_LiGothic-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Apple_LiSung-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Apple_Symbols-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Arial-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Arial-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Arial-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Arial-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Arial_Black-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Arial_Hebrew-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Arial_Hebrew-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Arial_Narrow-bold-italic-condensed-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Arial_Narrow-bold-normal-condensed-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Arial_Narrow-medium-italic-condensed-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Arial_Narrow-medium-normal-condensed-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Arial_Rounded_MT_Bold-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Arial_Unicode_MS-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Ayuthaya-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Baghdad-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Baskerville-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Baskerville-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Baskerville-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Baskerville-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-BiauKai-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Big_Caslon-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Brush_Script_MT-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Chalkboard-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Chalkboard-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Chalkduster-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Charcoal_CY-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Cochin-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Cochin-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Cochin-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Cochin-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Comic_Sans_MS-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Comic_Sans_MS-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Copperplate-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Copperplate-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Corsiva_Hebrew-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Corsiva_Hebrew-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Courier-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Courier-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Courier-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Courier-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Courier_New-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Courier_New-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Courier_New-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Courier_New-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
-apple-DecoType_Naskh-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Devanagari_MT-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Devanagari_MT-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Didot-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Didot-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Didot-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Euphemia_UCAS-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Euphemia_UCAS-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Euphemia_UCAS-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Futura-bold-normal-condensed-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Futura-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Futura-medium-normal-condensed-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Futura-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-GB18030_Bitmap-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Geeza_Pro-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Geeza_Pro-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Geneva-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Geneva_CY-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Georgia-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Georgia-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Georgia-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Georgia-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Gill_Sans-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Gill_Sans-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Gill_Sans-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Gill_Sans-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Gujarati_MT-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-GungSeo-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Gurmukhi_MT-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-HeadLineA-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Hei-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Heiti_SC-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Heiti_SC-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Heiti_TC-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Heiti_TC-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Helvetica-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Helvetica-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Helvetica-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Helvetica-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Helvetica_CY-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Helvetica_CY-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Helvetica_CY-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Helvetica_CY-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Helvetica_Neue-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Helvetica_Neue-bold-normal-condensed-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Helvetica_Neue-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Helvetica_Neue-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Helvetica_Neue-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Herculanum-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Hiragino_Kaku_Gothic_Pro-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Hiragino_Kaku_Gothic_Pro-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Hiragino_Kaku_Gothic_ProN-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Hiragino_Kaku_Gothic_ProN-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Hiragino_Kaku_Gothic_Std-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Hiragino_Kaku_Gothic_StdN-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Hiragino_Maru_Gothic_Pro-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Hiragino_Maru_Gothic_ProN-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Hiragino_Mincho_Pro-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Hiragino_Mincho_Pro-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Hiragino_Mincho_ProN-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Hiragino_Mincho_ProN-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Hiragino_Sans_GB-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Hiragino_Sans_GB-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Hoefler_Text-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Hoefler_Text-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Hoefler_Text-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Hoefler_Text-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Impact-medium-normal-condensed-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-InaiMathi-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Kai-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Kailasa-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Kokonor-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Krungthep-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-KufiStandardGK-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-LiHei_Pro-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-LiSong_Pro-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Lucida_Grande-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Lucida_Grande-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Marker_Felt-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Marker_Felt-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Menlo-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Menlo-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Menlo-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Menlo-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Microsoft_Sans_Serif-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Microsoft_YaHei-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Monaco-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Mshtakan-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Mshtakan-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Mshtakan-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Mshtakan-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Nadeem-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-New_Peninim_MT-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-New_Peninim_MT-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-New_Peninim_MT-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-New_Peninim_MT-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Optima-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Optima-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Optima-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Optima-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Osaka-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Osaka-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-PCMyungjo-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Papyrus-medium-normal-condensed-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Papyrus-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-PilGi-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Plantagenet_Cherokee-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Raanana-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Raanana-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-STFangsong-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-STHeiti-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-STHeiti-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-STKaiti-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-STSong-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Sathu-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Silom-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Skia-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Symbol-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Tahoma-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Tahoma-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Thonburi-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Thonburi-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Times-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Times-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Times-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Times-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Times_New_Roman-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Times_New_Roman-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Times_New_Roman-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Times_New_Roman-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Trebuchet_MS-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Trebuchet_MS-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Trebuchet_MS-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Trebuchet_MS-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Verdana-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Verdana-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Verdana-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Verdana-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Webdings-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Wingdings-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Wingdings_2-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Wingdings_3-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Zapf_Dingbats-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
-apple-Zapfino-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Select a font that can display the character. You can use `set-default-font` or `set-frame-font`, for example.

Comment: How do I know which font to choose?

Comment: Regarding font support to the character, check out http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2465/fontsupport.htm

Comment: How to check current font used?